# Return from function in Kotlin as one-liner when object is null

Tags: kotlin

I have a Java method that looks like this:

```
void doStuff() {
    MyObject myObject = myObjectRepository.findById(myObjectId);
    if (myObject == null) {
        log.warn("myObject not found, aborting");
        return;
    }

    // More stuff
}
```

Is there a way to make this a one-liner in Kotlin? I'm thinking something like this (which doesn't work):

```
fun doStuff() {
    // I'd like to do something here that returns from the doStuff function when myObject is null
    val myObject = myObjectRepository.findById(myObjectId) 
                    ?: {log.warn("myObject not found, aborting") return}

   // More stuff
}
```

Can you do something like this Kotlin?

Comment: I personally don't think that would improve readability

Comment: you should use Elvis operator

Comment: and if it's a matter of typing less for a somewhat common scenario I would define a template in my ide with a name like ifnullret. Something like "if($var == null) log.warn($msg) return"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
fun doStuff() {

    val myObject = myObjectRepository.findById(myObjectId) 
                    ?: log.warn("myObject not found, aborting").also{ return }

   // More stuff
}
```

But I'd agree with DPM, a classical `if-else` is a better option.

You may want to consider also the `when` construct (depending on the size, the task of the function and the return type):

```
fun doStuff() {

    val myObject = myObjectRepository.findById(myObjectId) 

    return when {
        myObject == null -> log.warn("myObject not found, aborting") // Unit?
        else -> // More stuff
    }
}
```

One of the reason you may prefer a `when` over an `if-else` is also because I find it exploits better the space (a readable `if-else` use at least 4, sometimes 5, loc) and it's more legible because you have the keyword `when` at the same level of the return (or assign, or whatever) and each case pure and simple without any additional keywords, simply a non-literal sign `->` that clearly states the condition from the code.

However, `also` is an extention function offered by the kotlin standard lib.
It's one of the features I love most about Kotlin which gives you a lot of power and expressiveness.

Let me suggest you this [link](https://lmller.github.io/kotlin-standard-extensions) to further investigate and learn more about other useful functions, such `run`, `let`, `apply`, `takeUnless` and `takeIf`

Answer (score 4):

```
 val myObject = myObjectRepository.findById(myObjectId)?:run { 
   log.warn("myObject not found, aborting"); return
 }
 //more stuff
```